# N+にわたって/にわたり/にわたる

Tags: grammar

Can someone explain me the exact meaning of にわたって when used in describing time/ duration? I understand its use for range when we describe space. And I know it can mean something like "over a period of", but I saw it also means prolongation of time. Also, isn't 間 alone for duration? Why do we need にわたって?

So, what is the difference here:

> 私は ３時間 勉強しました。
>   私は ３時間**にわたって** 勉強しました。

Hope you'll understand what I want to say. I'm confused because for one moment I understand it and *poof* it's gone.

Comment: Does "spanning" or "extending" help understand it any better?

Answer (score 2):

にわたって and its variations emphasize that the activity covered a long (or longer than expected) period. In English, the nuance is something like this:

> I studied for three hours.
>
> I studied for *three whole hours.*

I feel like にわたって also has somewhat of a formal/written sound to it.

A reference:  [Learn JLPT N2 Grammar: にわたって (ni watatte)](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-ni-watatte/)

Comment: The second example in that link is `大学入試は一週間にわたって行われます。` and is translated as "The university entrance exams will be held **in** one week."  That seems wrong to me, and even goes against the page's own definition.  I would translate it as "...will be held **over (a period of)** one week."